# Jenkins - set timeout to Stage and continue with next stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have a stage which runs one shell script at remote node. If the script takes very long time to execute, the stage should wait for sometime and should move to next stage without aborting the subsequent stages.

Could you please let me know the required syntax to achieve this.

Answer (score 10):

in a declarative pipeline, add this stage:

```
stage ("do-and-skip-for-timeout") {
   steps {
      script {
        try {
          timeout (time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
             echo "do something here, that can take some time" // replace this line with your code
          }
        }
        catch (error) {
           def user = error.getCauses()[0].getUser()
           if('SYSTEM' == user.toString()) { // SYSTEM means timeout.
             echo "Timeout reached, continue to next stage"
           } 
           else {
             throw new Exception("[ERROR] stage failed!")
           }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this input. Its really a worth.

Comment: If it helped to solve the issue, please vote up and mark the question as 'answered' so people will use it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @yorammi, it's working like a magic. +1 for the answer.

Comment: if the user clicks on the pipeline's Stop button, that will be also as "SYSTEM"...

Comment: @andras.tim you are probably right, but it has no conflict with the question asked